# Write code in C to convert Decimal to any base Where am I going wrong

Tags: c

```
int convert(int v, int r) //v=value, r=base
{
    int result=0;
    int i=0;
    volatile int remainder = 0;
    while(v > 0){
        remainder = v%r;  //get remainder
        v /= r;  // find the new divisor
        i++;            
    }
    return result;
}

int main(){
    int value = 6;  //convert decimal 6 to binary
    int base = 2;

    volatile int result = 0;
    result = convert(value,base);

    printf(value, base);  

    int base16 = 16;
    int value16 = 50;
    volatile int result16 = 0;
```

I was given a template with a while loop and main as a starting point to write a program to convert a decimal number to any base. How do I write a print statement given that I have the mathematical information already in the code?

Comment: You used the C++ language tag, but nothing in the code you show is specific to C++. Are you sure you picked the correct tag? And if you're programming C (and not C++) then you should get a couple of good beginners books, because you make some mistakes that tells me you haven't cared much about that. And the same if you're really trying to be programming in C++.

Comment: Why do you mark everything as volatile? That's a very bad idea.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : +1 for the constructive advice.

Comment: _"I don't understand the while loop"_ But you're the one who wrote it? Dumping a broken program and saying "I don't understand" a couple of times does not a SO question make.

Comment: The loop does nothing other than a generate a math error if `r` is zero.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Your `convert` function is meaningless, it's just doing some arithmetic and returning 0 all the time. The `volatile` use here is unnecessary here, why do you use that?

Answer (score 2):

All your `convert` function does is return 0. Scrap that function and start over. You have the right idea with

```
while(v > 0){
        remainder = v%r;
        v /= r;
```

But you need to store each remainder separately. Taking `v` modulo `r` gives you the remainder of the division between `v` and `r`. Each remainder gives you the next place value going from lowest order to highest order. Do something like this

```
int convert (int[], int, int);
int print_base2 (int[], int);

int main ()
{
    int value = 6;
    int base = 2;
    int result[40]; // Enough space for binary if INT_MAX is 2^31 - 1
    int places_written, i;

    places_written = convert (result, value, base);

    if (base == 2)
        print_base2 (result, places_written);
}

int convert (int result[], int value, int base)
{
    int remainder, i = 0;

    while (value > 0) {
        remainder = value % base; // Get next place value
        value /= base; // Move over value by one place
        result[i++] = remainder; // Store the place value
    }

    return i;
}


void print_base2 (int result[], int places_written)
{
    int i;

    // Go backwards and print each value
    for (i = places_written; i > 0; i--) {
        if (result[i - 1] == 1)
            printf ("%c", '1');
        else if (result[i - 1] == 0)
            printf ("%c", '0');
    }
}
```

Note: there are better ways to get and print numbers if you just want to use base 2, but you can model the rest of your functions based on `print_base2`. And stop declaring everything `volatile`. That's a bad idea.

Edit: You should check if `base` is zero in `convert` before the while loop because your program will crash if `base` is zero.

Comment: Good answer. But in the `print_base2` you could do `printf("1"); `and `printf("0");`. Or even better `printf("%d", result[i-1]);`. Also add a `fflush(stdout);` before leaving the function so that the output is printed on screen, otherwise it could take a while until it's printed.

Comment: I chose to do `printf ("%c", '1');` to demonstrate how to do it if the base and value isn't something printf can output (i.e. not decimal or hexadecimal). I said in my answer there are better ways to do it in the case of binary, but printing 27 ('r') in a `print_base36` function is going to require this method. Good point about `fflush (stdout);`.

Comment: Could you not use the `place_written` variable and just check if there is a value in `result[i]` before incrementing it ?